# Grafana. How to add values from query in alert message

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

Grafana 8.2.5. I have a query (from Postgre datasource)

```
SELECT
  ts AS "time",
  voltage_a,
  voltage_b,
  voltage_c
FROM "PowerValues"
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(ts) AND
  section = 'Electricity'
ORDER BY 1
```

I have configured an alert for this query
![alert configuration] (https://i.imgur.com/jdHS8gZ.png)
It is working well and send alerts in my telegram channel. But I can't add values from the query into the notification message. I tried a different combinations

```
Low/high voltage
${voltage_a}

L1={{ $value }}
L1={{ $values }}
L1={{ $labels }}
{{ $labels.A.voltage_a }}
{{ $label.A.voltage_a }}
{{ $values.A.voltage_a }}
{{ $value.A.voltage_a }}
```

All these mustaches strings are sent to my channel, no values are substituted. Is it possible to add values from the query, that raised this alert?

Comment: I'd love to know the same. I'm trying to get the value of a query as well. Have you tried the Percona forums?